# How dangerous are SWEET32 and LUCKY13 vulnerabilities?

Tags: attacks, vulnerability

I wonder how vulnerable are Sweet32 and Lucky13? I mean, how often do the attackers use these vulnerabilities to gain access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucky13 and Sweet32 are both attacks on SSL/TLS, i.e. these attacks can be used to intercept the encrypted connection between the client and the server.  In the case of a server that is vulnerably to Lucky13, an active attacker may be able to launch a MITM attack by exploiting this vulnerability.  The same applies to Sweet32, but even a passive attacker may be able to decrypt the encrypted data if they are able to collect enough data.  However, neither attack can be used to gain access to the server.

Comment: How do I fix these vulnerabilities on debian?

Comment: @rubo77 Remove CBC cipher support from your webserver SSL ciphers.